# PHP PEAR Mail->send success/failure result?

Tags: php, email, error-handling, pear

From a PHP5 script, I am sending e-mail with PEAR's Mail class:

```
$message =& Mail::factory('mail');
$message->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

How can I know if the sending of the message was successful or if there was a failure?

Comment: look at the docu: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At most you can detect a failure when PHP hands the email over to the SMTP server. e.g. when `->send()` returns false. Any other failure is completely out of PHP's hands. E.g. if the email bounces, or the address is invalid, etc... that'll happen at the SMTP server level, and the errors for that do NOT come back to PHP. In that case, you'd have to check the reply-to address to see if there's any bounce notices.

Comment: How does `->send()` return False? Can you write a small one-liner example please? Thank you!

Comment: sorry, was thinking of a different mail package. PEAR mail, right? it'll return a PEAR object error on failure: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php